# Having trouble with query giving different results inside subform vs just running query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to use a query to make a list of records for use in a subform. This will allow a user to pick the record they want to edit. With no changes to the SQL or tables I get different results running the query directly or using the same query as the recordsource of my form.

households has a record for each address - h_id is the ID number 
people is a list of people in each household - household_id links to a household

Query SQL

```
SELECT P.last_name, H.h_id, P.first_name, H.second_last_name, H.address, H.mailing_address, H.phone, H.second_phone FROM households AS H INNER JOIN people AS P ON H.h_id = P.household_id WHERE (((P.last_name) Is Not Null))
```

the only difference in the form is that I have to put the WHERE part under Filter

if the query is run alone I get

```
last_name       h_id    first_name  address 
Johnson         1289    Mike        26 Aiken Ave        
Raty- Johnson   1289    Mary        26 Aiken Ave
```

when the query is the recordsource for the form I get

```
last_name       h_id    first_name  address
Raty- Johnson   1289    Mary        26 Aiken Ave
```

So far I assume that the form is killing the second record for maybe matching h_id, but I have no idea how to stop it. The output from running the query alone is what I want, only in the form. This will allow the form to have other people in the household listed, in case one of them come instead of the person who signed up.

Comment: Normally a form is used to enter/edit data for one table. Which table do you want to edit - People? Why don't you bind main form to Household and subform to People? "In case one of them come instead" - come where, is there another table involved?

Comment: This program is for a foodbank and keeps track of people to give information that the regional foodbank uses to decide how much food to give us. This form is a list of households that can be searched by is number, name of any people in the house, or address. This form edits nothing, just opens another form that does editing. The problem I'm having is getting all people on the form. Showing only the person who signed up is easy - their name is in household. I'm trying to link the people table to get the other names. A web article from Microsoft said an inner join would work.

Comment: INNER JOIN on household ID key fields should allow display of all people and their associated household info. Should not need to have the WHERE criteria in form Filter property. No way to determine what is going wrong on form without viewing it.

Comment: The only thing the WHERE does is filter out people with no name AKA children who won't be there to get food.

Comment: My problem at the moment is that the same query behaves differently depending on where it is.

Comment: Query is used as subform RecordSource. So is the subform linked to data on main form?

Comment: No. The purpose of the main form is only to pick a date to enter info for, pick from a list of  reports to run them, and have the subform showing people to edit. There is also a new person button.

Comment: Unfortunately, would have to review db to analyze this issue. Issue quite possibly is design, not code, and therefore question not appropriate for SO.